# How to move image view in xml

Tags: android, xml

I am new in android development and i am using eclipse java to develop an app.My problem is that i want to locate the elements like image view or button to wherever i want like it is in the Adobe Flash.How can i do that.Relative layout puts elements relative to other objects.Should i change the relative layout and what should i change it into?( i mean which layout)
Thanks
Here is my code.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ff8D8D8D"
    tools:context="com.example.deniz.MainActivity" >
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView1" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:scaleType="fitXY" android:src="@drawable/back"/>
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/close" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:onClick="close_app" android:src="@drawable/exit"/>
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/new_project" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_marginLeft="22dp" android:layout_marginTop="24dp" android:onClick="open_new" android:src="@drawable/buttonm"/>
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/little" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/new_project" android:layout_below="@+id/new_project" android:layout_marginLeft="16dp" android:layout_marginTop="18dp" android:src="@drawable/buttonm"/>
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/ImageView01" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:layout_marginBottom="16dp" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/new_project" android:scaleType="fitCenter" android:src="@drawable/buttonm"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You can locate any view by its id. For example your first imageView can be located by the id "imageView1"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a veteran Android developer (which my Reputation clearly reflects), but with the humble experience that I have, I think I'll give your problem a shot.

You should stick to RelativeLayout and use any of/a mix of these functions:

- [setX(float x) / setY(float y)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setX%28float%29) - Available for versions above HoneyComb
- setLayoutParams(LayoutParams params)

One not much recommended or used ViewGroup is the [AbsoluteLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsoluteLayout.html) which, in definition, is exactly what you're looking for.

Though mostly used layouts - say, LinearLayout, RelativeLayout - have enough possibility to implement most designs, I hope my answer helps you achieve what you're aiming to do.

Happy development!

Cheers!